# Input 0 of layer sequential_10 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=2

Tags: tensorflow, keras, reshape, conv-neural-network

Before reshaping xtraindata and xtest data, I got error:
"Input 0 of layer sequential_10 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=2.". After reshaping xtraindata and xtestdata as (1400,24,24,1) and (600,24,24,1) in order. Then I got error like this:
"Incompatible shapes: [32,1] vs. [32,6,6,1]
[[node mean_squared_error/SquaredDifference (defined at C:\Users\User\Documents\car_person.py:188) ]] [Op:__inference_test_function_7945]

Function call stack:
test_function"
I cannot make evaluate function working on created model. What should I do in order to make test data compatible with model?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import time
import cv2
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import itertools as it
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if gpus:
  try:
    tf.config.experimental.set_virtual_device_configuration(gpus[0], [tf.config.experimental.VirtualDeviceConfiguration(memory_limit=4096)])
  except RuntimeError as e:
    print(e)


#gpu_options=K.tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.35)

path = "C:/Users/User/Desktop/tunel_data"
training_data=[]

def create_training_data(training_data, path):
    categories = ["tunel_data_other", "tunel_data_car"]
    for category in categories:
        path=os.path.join(path, category)
        for img in os.listdir(path):
            print(img)
            if category=="tunel_data_other":
                class_num= 0
                #image=Image.open(img)
                #new_image = image.resize((50, 50))
                #new_image.save('car'+img.index())
                #try:
                image_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, img), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)/255
                new_array = cv2.resize(image_array, (24, 24))
                print(new_array.shape)
                training_data.append([new_array, class_num])
                #except:
                    #pass
            elif category=="tunel_data_car":
                class_num = 1
                #image=Image.open(img)
                #new_image = image.resize((50, 50))
                #new_image.save('person'+img.index())
                #try:
                image_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, img), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)/255
                new_array = cv2.resize(image_array, (24, 24))
                print(new_array.shape)
                training_data.append([new_array, class_num])
                #except:
                    #pass
        path = "C:/Users/User/Desktop/tunel_data"
    return training_data

create_training_data(training_data, path)

x=[]
y=[]

for i in range(len(training_data)):
    x.append(training_data[i][0])
    y.append(training_data[i][1])
#print(x)
#print(y)
     
x = np.array(x).reshape(2000, 576)
"""
principle_features = PCA(n_components=250)
feature = principle_features.fit_transform(x)
"""
feature = x
label = y

feature_df = pd.DataFrame(feature)

#df = DataFrame (People_List,columns=['First_Name','Last_Name','Age'])

label_df = pd.DataFrame(label)


data = pd.concat([feature_df, label_df], axis=1).to_csv('complete.csv')


data = pd.read_csv("complete.csv")

data = data.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)

print(data)

x_test, x_train, y_test, y_train = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.7, random_state=65)
xtraindata=pd.DataFrame(data=x_train[:,:])
xtestdata=pd.DataFrame(data=x_test[:,:])
print(xtraindata)

ytraindata=pd.DataFrame(data=y_train[:])
ytestdata=pd.DataFrame(data=y_test[:])
print(ytraindata)

xtraindata = np.asarray(xtraindata)
ytraindata = np.asarray(ytraindata)
xtestdata = np.asarray(xtestdata)
ytestdata = np.asarray(ytestdata)
x=np.asarray(x)
y=np.asarray(y)


xtraindata = xtraindata.reshape(1400,24,24,1)
xtestdata = xtestdata.reshape(600,24,24,1)

activation = ["tanh", "relu", "sigmoid", "softmax"]
input_size1 = range(10)
input_size2 = range(10)
k_scores = []
in_size = []

possible = list(it.permutations(activation, 4))

for c in possible:
    for i in input_size1:
        for a in input_size2:
            model = tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'),
                                         tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)),
                                         tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'),
                                         tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)),
                                         tf.keras.layers.Dense(250, activation=c[0]),
                                         tf.keras.layers.Dense(i, activation=c[1]),
                                         tf.keras.layers.Dense(a, activation=c[2]),
                                         tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=c[3])])
            model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mse')
            val_loss = model.evaluate(xtestdata, ytestdata, verbose=1)
            k_scores.append(val_loss)
            in_size.append([i,a])
            
print(k_scores)
print("Best activation functions for each layer:", possible[(k_scores.index((min(k_scores)))) % len(possible)],
      "/n Best input sizes:", "840", in_size[k_scores.index((min(k_scores)))][0], in_size[k_scores.index((min(k_scores)))][1], "1")

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(250, activation=possible[(k_scores.index((min(k_scores)))) % len(possible)][0]))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(in_size[k_scores.index((min(k_scores)))][0], activation=possible[(k_scores.index((min(k_scores)))) % len(possible)][1]))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(in_size[k_scores.index((min(k_scores)))][1], activation=possible[(k_scores.index((min(k_scores)))) % len(possible)][2]))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=possible[(k_scores.index((min(k_scores)))) % len(possible)][3]))
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy", "mse"])
model.fit(x, y, batch_size=16, epochs=5)
predictions = model.predict([x_test])
print(predictions)
print(predictions.shape)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

output layer size is different. you want size `(32, 1)` but model's output is `(32, 6, 6, 1)`

insert `Flatten()` between `MaxPooling2D` and `Dense()` maybe this work's well.

and here is the tip. `.evaluate` method is only for trained model. you should use `.fit` first.